# What are the implications of Baudrillard's ideas to epistemology?

Tags: epistemology, postmodernism

I would simply like to know what you guys think... what points does his social theory, including his concept of hyperreality, intersect with theory of knowledge?

Comment: Can you share what you might imagine them to be?

Comment: Okay, I’m about 8 years too late, but when I read them my first time the initial thought was that this was an epistemological theory overlaid upon a theory of media. Like, what is media but a form of the collective unconscious. Is anyone still here? Any thoughts on this 7+ years later?